How to reboot into Windows from Linux without timeout in Grub menu (faster reboot)
I want to ask if this is achievable with grub. I am having difficulty finding if there is a way to set grub timeout to 0 or timeout style to hidden only once when booting, and then back to default. I want to achieve this with a script I run before rebooting.
What I currently have is this: when I want to reboot into Windows after  using Linux, I have a script that will set the grub menu to select the Windows bootloader one time when rebooting and then restart. Any subsequent boots will default to first entry (Linux). The script is super simple:
sudo grub-reboot 3 && reboot

The problem is waiting for the boot menu to timeout, because I know I want to boot into Windows. I want something like grub-reboot but for timeout or hiding boot selection and going straight to Windows just once. It is more of a QOL improvement than anything.
I am open to more hackier solutions to the level of say, the Windows reboot script updating the grub config timeout to 0, then when I boot grub it sets the timeout back to default, like a hook script that calls after grub is booted. Hopefully a stable solution with low risk of breaking anything.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please don't quote me on this (I don't want to be associated with such an unholy suggestion), but for the sake of science, technically speaking I suppose you could brutally append set timeout=0 to /boot/grub/grub.cfg before rebooting and remove it on the next boot with something like sed -i '$d' /boot/grub/grub.cfg. Please don't do it. Hopefully there's a proper answer to this.

Gamester1128: The answer may depend on which Linux. Can you edit your question and add the Linux you are using.

This answer was tested with using the following Linux distributions.

EndeavourOS installed from EndeavourOS_Endeavour_neo-2024.09.22.iso
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS

Grub allows for customizations, which can be stored in the /boot/grub/custom.cfg file. Normally, this file does not exist, which means you may need to create this file. You should edit this file as the root user. The command I used to edit this file is given below.
sudo nano /boot/grub/custom.cfg


Note: You do not need to execute sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg after making changes to this file. Ubuntu users do not need to execute sudo update-grub after making changes to this file.

Below is an example of what to add to this file.
if [ "$default" == 3 ]; then
  set timeout=0
fi


I will point out that you can also do the following. Instead of setting the one time boot to 3, you could choose an arbitrarily large number, such as 1000. Then you could enter the following.
sudo grub-reboot 1000 && reboot

In this case, you would add the following to the /boot/grub/custom.cfg file.
if [ "$default" == 1000 ]; then
  set default=3
  set timeout=0
fi


Response to Comments
The OP posted the following as comments.

I use EndeavourOS. To add to the answer, for endeavour I added it to /etc/grub.d/40_custom since the file sounds like where I should add it (which may be specific to endeavour or arch?) and then ran sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg to regenerate the grub config. PS: That is exactly what I wanted, especially liked the other solution. . . . Also would like to add that I tested your solution (adding to /boot/grub/custom.cfg) on endeavour and it worked flawlessly. Can't decide which file to edit is more "correct" for endeavour. What I like about yours is not needing to run grub-mkconfig. Simple and clean solution!

I think editing /etc/grub.d/41_custom would be more appropriate than changing /etc/grub.d/40_custom. However, consider the following. The contents of /etc/grub.d/41_custom is shown below.
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF
if [ -f  \${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source \${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "\${config_directory}" -a -f  \$prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source \$prefix/custom.cfg
fi
EOF

The above script instructs Grub to execute the contents of the file /boot/grub/custom.cfg, if the file exists. So there reallly is no need to edit /etc/grub.d/41_custom. Instead, you can just put your customizations in /boot/grub/custom.cfg.

I use EndeavourOS. To add to the answer, for endeavour I added it to /etc/grub.d/40_custom since the file sounds like where I should add it (which may be specific to endeavour or arch?) and then ran sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg to regenerate the grub config. PS: That is exactly what I wanted, especially liked the other solution. Thanks!

@Gamester1128: Thanks for responding. I will test with EndeavourOS and update my answer. You can check back later, if you wish.

Thanks for double checking. Also would like to add that I tested your solution (adding to /boot/grub/custom.cfg) on endeavour and it worked flawlessly. Can't decide which file to edit is more "correct" for endeavour. What I like about yours is not needing to run grub-mkconfig. Simple and clean solution!

I will assume that in 2024 you're running both operating systems in UEFI boot mode (as opposed to legacy BIOS boot).
The EFI firmware has its own boot menu with similar ability to select the "next" boot entry from within a running OS, which you can do either from Windows or Linux.
Even though you're currently going through GRUB to boot Windows, you most likely still have a direct "Windows Boot Manager" EFI boot entry alongside the "GRUB" entry (or if you don't, it's easy enough to add back), so you can use efibootmgr to boot directly into it without having to go through the GRUB menu at all:
# efibootmgr
 BootCurrent: 0001
 BootOrder: 0000,0001
 Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
 Boot0001* Ubuntu
 Boot001F  USB HDD

# efibootmgr --bootnext 0000

# reboot

See older thread for the Windows equivalent.

Sorry, this may a be a stupid question, but is editing the EFI boot manager order a lot potentially bad for wherever the data is stored? I remember reading older computers stored firmware "stuff" on memory that had limited writes so I worry about it. I have no idea how and where UEFI and other booting software is stored and it's limitations. I do like this solution as I may save time directly booting rather than using Grub as a jump host.

It's possible, since it's all kept on the mainboard's NVRAM/"CMOS" memory, but most (especially newer) mainboards shouldn't be that limited in this regard. The BootOrder/BootNext variables themselves are small, and many new mainboards store their settings in the same place (often even visible among the other EFI variables), and the write limit should be in the "tens of thousands" at least (assuming the firmware has halfway decent flash wear leveling), so I don't expect it to cause problems on any reasonably modern system.
